# Python: What function would I use to locate the highest population from this .CVS file?

Tags: python

What function would I use to locate the highest population from a .CSV file?

Here is the dataset:

```
ID,NAME,CITY,COUNTRY,CPERSON,EMPLCNT,CONTRCNT,CONTRCOST
00000001,Breadpot,Sydney,Australia,Sam.Keng@info.com,250,48,1024.00
00000002,Hoviz,Manchester,UK,harry.ham@hoviz.com,150,7,900.00
00000003,Hoviz,London,UK,hamlet.host@hoviz.com,1500,12800,10510.50
00000004,Grenns,London,UK,grenns@grenns.com,200,12800,128.30
00000005,Magnolia,Chicago,USA,man@info.com,1024,25600,512000.00
00000006,Dozen,San Francisco,USA,dozen@dozen.com,1000,5,1000.20
00000007,Sun,San Francisco,USA,sunny@sun.com,2000,2,10000.01
```

I am brand new to this language and thoroughly stumped on this one. Please explain your answers in a way that I can understand or if you could share a link to some kind of tutorial for a full explanation that would be great also.

Comment: Do you mean CSV? because it looks like CSV.

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to the language and this one's got me stumped. Maybe I didn't post the question correctly? I have no idea where to start on this one.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. More links the better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use `pandas`, which is a data analysis library. I'm not sure which column represents "population", but you would do it like this:

**Install pandas, then...**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')  
df['POPULATION_COLUMN_NAME'].max()
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Sources:

- Installing pandas : https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Sipkd9vNKk
- read_csv(): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
- max(): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Answer (score 1):

For reading csv I would use the pandas module. This [tutorial](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-pandas-tutorial-complete-introduction-for-beginners/) is great.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv_file.csv')
```

Im not sure with column corresponds to population; taking `EMPLCNT` as an example

```
df['EMPLCNT'].max()
2000
```